# Using MAMP 3.4, how do I upgrade to Apache 2.4 and OpenSSL 1.0.2 to meet the ATS iOS 9 requirements?

Tags: xcode, apache, ios, openssl, mamp

I've just installed MAMP 3.4 on Yosemite but the Apache version inside is still 2.2. Is there a way to upgrade to Apache 2.4? Moreover I have installed through brew openssl 1.0.2 but MAMP Apache still starts with version OpenSSL/0.9.8zg. Why? I need this updates in order to meet new ATS iOS 9 requirements.

Comment: Interesting - I would have to wonder if this would be easier with a VM - using Vagrant or something to help instead of using MAMP altogether? Either way, I suggest you answer your own question by moving your edited-in solution to an answer. This will make it clearer for other users who are in search of a similar solution.

Comment: Thank u for your comment. I'm afraid I don't know what Vagrant is but the idea of a VM maybe is quite good. Anyway remember that MAMP can't be used because actually it runs only apache 2.2 while apache 2.4.x is strictly required for TLS 1.2

Comment: Ah - I missed that all important note in your answer. [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) just helps you manage VMs. You would write some provisioning scripts which would build your machine with the tools that you would need, and then `vagrant up` to run all of them and boot the VM.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately I know nothing about VMs and generally low level programming :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of July 21, 2016, there is a pre-release available of MAMP PRO 4 which includes OpenSSL 1.0.2, get the pre-release here:

https://www.mamp.info/en/pre-release.html

Comment: At last!! This is a very good piece of news! Thank you mate!

Comment: You're welcome, I was in the same position as you so had to share this info :)

Answer (score 4):

### For Mac OS X Yosemite

1. Update openssl by brew to version >= 1.0.2d
2. TLS 1.2 works **only with** apache 2.4 and actually MAMP is still given with apache 2.2. **SOLUTION:** download and install the latest version of [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com/downloads) which runs a version of apache 2.4.x
3. create a self signed certificate with sha256 (as requested by iOS 9) with

   `openssl req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt`

and save `server.key` and `server.crt` into `/Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf`

4. Be sure that ssl modules are loaded inside httpd.conf file of AMPPS
5. Edit file `/Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` adding:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/AMPPS/www"
   ServerName localhost
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
   SSLHonorCipherOrder on
   SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/server.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

inside

```
<IfModule ssl_module> ... </IfModule>
```

6. iOS 9 simulator will annoy you each time you use NSURLSession raising an error 9813 saying that the certificate is not valid (because is self signed). So in each class where you are going to use NSURLSession do, for example, the following:

```
class LoginService: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    task: NSURLSessionTask,
    didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?)
    -> Void) {

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

...

func requestLoginWithURL (requestURL: NSURL, completionHandler: (success: Bool?) -> Void) {
    let configuration =
    NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    /*
    dataTaskWithRequest: creates an HTTP request for the specified URL request object, and calls a handler upon completion.
    */
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

...
}
```

where the function `URLSession` is a delegate which will prevent the app from crashing because of the self signed certificate and it will accept anyway.